# Using oneside command changes alot of my commands

Tags: header-footer, document-classes, single-sided

I am currently writing my Thesis and I am using a template form the university of Bamberg in Germany (https://github.com/UBA-PSI/psi-thesis-guide). When I add in the documentclass the command oneside and load it than my \cleardubblepage and the header dissapear. Do you maybe know why?

There are alot of commands in this template so to be honest i am not even sure what command to add in here.

```
    \documentclass[
12pt, % The default document font size is 11 (recommended), options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two-side layout is recommended; uncomment to switch to one-sided
ngerman, % replace with ngerman for German; not fully supported so far -- requires changes elsewhere
onehalfspacing, % Single line spacing (recommended), alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add list of figures/tables/etc to table of contents (not recommended)
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents (not recommended)
parskip, % add space between paragraphs (recommended)
nohyperref, % do not load the hyperref package (is loaded in setup.tex)
%headsepline, % print a horizontal line under the page header
consistentlayout, % layout of declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages matches the default layout
%final, % Uncomment to hide all todo notes
]{PSIThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
```

I appreciate any help and if some of you know might have a clue what kind of other commands might be a problem I would add them to this post.

I am sorry for not knowing which of all the commands to add here...

PS. The headers on even and uneven pages disappeared.

These are my headder and footer commands.

```
\newlength{\overflowingheadlen}
\setlength{\overflowingheadlen}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\overflowingheadlen}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\overflowingheadlen}{\marginparwidth}

% old header/footer, maybe not necessary any more?
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\ihead{\textup{\headmark}} % Inner header; do not use italics: therefore textup
\ihead{\textup{\textsc{\MakeLowercase\headmark}}}% Inner header - use this line for Small Caps in header
\ohead[]{\pagemark} % Outer header
\cfoot[\pagemark]{} % On chapter opening pages, the page number goes centered into the footer
\automark*[section]{}%

% new header/footer, from kaobook; we could probably remove the original definitions from the cls
\renewpagestyle{thesis}{
  {\hspace{-\marginparwidth}\hspace{-\marginparsep}\makebox[\overflowingheadlen][l]{\textup{\thepage}\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\quad{}\textup{\textsc{\MakeLowercase \leftmark}}}}%
  {\makebox[\overflowingheadlen][r]{\textup{\textsc{\MakeLowercase \rightmark}}\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\quad\textup{\thepage}}}%
  {}
}{
  {}%
  {}%
  {}
}
\renewpagestyle{plain.thesis}{
  {}%
  {}%
  {}
}{
  {\hspace{-\marginparwidth}\hspace{-\marginparsep}\makebox[\overflowingheadlen][l]{\textup{\textsc{\thepage}}\quad\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}}}%
  {\makebox[\overflowingheadlen][r]{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\baselineskip}\quad\textup{\textsc{\thepage}}}}%
  {}
}


\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

% We use lining figures for headers (tlfstyle) because they fit better with uppercase letters than old-style figures.

% chapters have a vertical line between number and title
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries\tlfstyle}{\color{black}\thechapter}{20pt}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\color{black}\vrule width 2pt\hsp}p{0.85\textwidth}}\raggedright #1\end{tabular}}

% sections
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\large\tlfstyle}{{\color{black}\thechapter.\arabic{section}}}{1ex}{{\color{black} #1}}{}

% subsections
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\large\tlfstyle}{{\color{black}\thechapter.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}}{1ex}{{\color{black} #1}}{}

% subsubsections
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries\tlfstyle}{{\color{black}\thechapter.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}}{1ex}{{\color{black} #1}}{}

%paragraph
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\bfseries\tlfstyle}{{\color{black}\thechapter.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragrpah}}}{1ex}{{\color{black} #1}}{}
```

Comment: `oneside` makes  latex use the odd side layout on all pages, so `\cleardoublepage` is `\clearpage` and any page headings specified for even pages are not used

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the weird thing is that all of the headings disappeared, not only those on the even pages

Comment: perhaps your class does `\if@twoside  have headingss \else no headings\fi` as it a local class we don't have, and you have shown no code, it is impossible to say anything.

Comment: I am aware that i have shown no code, because i am not even sure which part of the code  I would have to add...

Comment: it is easy for you to find that and impossible for us. make a small one page document with a  header that goes if you add `oneside` then delete every line of the classs you can delete while still showing the problem,  but you have used inner and outer headings in the code you just showed, they do nothing for one sided documents (I would guess, depending how they are defined,they are not standard commands)